# Is there a way to prevent the Windows 10 keyboard sitting on top of a program?

Tags: windows-10, tablet, on-screen-keyboard

I really like using Windows 10 in tablet mode, but a huge issue I have is that the pop-up keyboard sits above the program or app that I'm using. This is a real pain when I'm using something like a word processor and the text starts to flow to the bottom of the window. You then either have to keep scrolling or resize the Window. Even then that's not ideal as if you rotate the device you have to do the same.

What I would like to do is have the program resize to sit or dock against the keyboard, much like any phone or tablet app. Then when the keyboard disappears, the program fills the screen again.

Is there a way to make Windows 10 use this behaviour?